# clearing date field inspite of giving readonly

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsp, date

This is how I defined a field for date.

```
<td colspan="2" height="22px">
    <input type="text" readonly="readonly"  name="fromDate" id="fromDate" size="35%">
</td>
```

I tried

```
$("#fromDate").keypress(function(e) {
    switch(e.keyCode) { 
        case 46:  // delete
        case 8:  // backspace
          break;
        default:
            e.preventDefault();
            break;
    }
});
```

When I use the above piece, I am able to use backspace and delete. For numbers the e.keyCode gives only 0 as value in alert box !! arrows work

This makes my field non editable. Like I am not able to use backspace. I need readonly so I can't remove it. Can someone help me out to achieve editing the field with backspace/delete for this field ?

Thanks

Understood that it is not logical to give room to type numbers. Rest of the stuff works correct. Thanks for the suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

`readonly` means just that - no `key` events will be handled and the input can only be amended programmatically. If you want the value to be cleared you need to include a separate element to use as a 'clear' button:

```
<td colspan="2" height="22px">
    <input type="text" readonly="readonly"  name="fromDate" id="fromDate" size="35%">
    <button class="clear-date">Clear</button>
</td>
```

```js
$('.clear-date').click(function() {
    $('#fromDate').val('');
});
```

Comment: I have to clear it by putting the cursor on the field and by keeping a separate button to reset it.

Comment: @sahana you mean while clicking reset button you need to clear the text box and focus the same?

Comment: I got solution. Thanks for the help Rory and Vinoth

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#fromDate").keypress(function(e) {
    switch(e.keyCode) { 
        case 46:  // delete
        case 8:  // backspace
          break;
        default:
            e.preventDefault();
            break;
    }
});
```